# Go wire multiple binding issue

Tags: go, dependency-injection, autowired

I've dependencies in following pattern

```
C -> B (B dependent on C)
C -> A (A dependent on C)
A, B -> D  (D dependent on A, B)
```

Here when I try to build wire for D, it throws multiple binding error for C. I'm using google wiring. How can I resolve multiple binding issue in this case ? or is there any other way I can handle these dependencies ?

I'm expecting D to get wired with A and B without explicitly defining dependency C while building wire for D.